# Split content of a div into 2 divisions

Tags: html, css

I was trying to implement splitting of entire content to create a slideshow. Something similar to this.

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/

The problem is splitting of divisions equally. I just don't want them to appear to be split but actually split with the first div containing all content but only top 50% height of actual content, and second div containing all content but having only bottom 50% height of original div.

Here's what I have so far.

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
.slide1, .slide2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    color: #AAA;
}

.slide1 {
    background: #F00;
}
.slide2 {
    top: 50%;
    background: #0F0;
}
```

Here's a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kz7c/).

UPDATE: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kz7c/4/) is what I want the end result to look like. This is just a quick hack that appears as though second div is split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same principle as that of vertical splitting can be used for horizontal as well. The HTML layout had to be modified a bit to get it working.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slide-wrapper">
        <div class="slide1">
            <div class="slide-content">Some content that has fixed width and positioned absolutely.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide2">
            <div class="slide-content">Some content that has fixed width and positioned absolutely.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Kz7c/8/

Answer (score 0):

This uses a jquery plugin call `FULLSCREEN SLIT SLIDER`
So You no need to implement it from the sketch.
Here you can find a tutorial how to use that and download the library.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/

**Edit:**

**css**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #222;
}

.reveal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.curve {
  background: url(http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/splitreveal/300.jpg) 0px 150px, url(http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/splitreveal/300.jpg) 0px -225px, #f6d9ad;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
  transition: background-position 0.3s ease;
}

.curve:hover {
  background: url(http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/splitreveal/300.jpg) 0px 210px, url(http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/splitreveal/300.jpg) 0px -285px, #f6d9ad;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.reveal p {
  font: 45px/300px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.reveal:hover p {
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="reveal curve">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z63ea/)

Comment: I don't have any problem with js. Just the CSS to split the divs. I'm creating a modified version of the slit slider.

Comment: You are actually changing the background position to make it appear as though the image is split. Height never comes into picture. I cannot do the same where div has text.

Answer (score 0):

If you just viewed source in the demo site you supplied, you might have seen this bit of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slitslider.js"></script>
```

And if you googled *jquery slitslider*, the first link you get is [FULLSCREEN SLIT SLIDER WITH JQUERY AND CSS3](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was referring the same for creating this. But the scenario is a bit different and hence their CSS won't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you looking for this..

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slide1, .slide2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #AAA;
}

.slide1 {
    background: #F00;
}
.slide2 {
    top: 50%;
    background: #0F0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Kz7c/3/

**EDIT:**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Kz7c/5/

Comment: Not exactly. When it's done, this is how it should look. http://jsfiddle.net/6Kz7c/4/. But I need the second div to have 50% height and only the bottom half.

Comment: I'm sorry but how is it different from the link I added in the comment? I actually need the second div to have 50% height having only the bottom half. Otherwise, when I add the animation, it doesn't give the split effect.

Comment: @nightgaunt, sorry i don't get you. http://jsfiddle.net/6Kz7c/5/ here first slide contain first 50% of content and slide2 contain last 50% content.

Comment: Yes. But if you look at the height of the divisions, first one is 50px and second one is 100px. When I add the animation, first div will fly off correctly, but second div moves as though it was overlapped by first div. The appearance is correct.

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kz7c/7/). I have done the same for vertical splitting but horizontal requires more gray matter I guess.